# Shopify reviews section takes time to load

Tags: javascript, e-commerce, shopify, liquid-layout

I have a shopify store. 
I havepulled the reviews section on `index.liquid` page.
When the page loads, the reviews section comes after 3-4 sec delay. As I am new to .liquid methods of shopify, can anyone suggest a few ways to improve this load time.

Answer (score 0):

[Shopify Reviews App](https://apps.shopify.com/product-reviews/?ref=microapps) is hosted on different servers than [Shopify](http://www.shopify.com/?ref=microapps) core. (I could almost tell you in Heroku). If Heroku is slow when sending you the data, I guess there's nothing you can do, but to wait for [Shopify](http://www.shopify.com/?ref=microapps) to put more petrol on it. Rest assured they will do.